# How do you fetch records from a table with order of another table using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my SQL, 'post' and 'business'
The columns in the post are:

- Post_ID
- Content
- Img
- Business_ID

The columns in business are

- Business_ID
- Business name
- Business rating

What I want is I want the posts which are posted by businesses with high business rating come first before others, please is there a way to fetch the posts with order of business rating???

Answer (score 0):

To order results of posts with associated business rating you need a join query

```
select p.*
from posts as p
join business as b on b.business_id = p.business_id
order by b.business_rating desc
```

Answer (score 0):

To arrange the ratting use `order by` query

```
select * from posts,business order by business_rating where posts.business_ID=business.business_ID;
```